# Spring resttemplate return 400 bad request

Tags: spring-mvc, resttemplate

My postman request with an empty body for post request works fine.

However when I try to do the same with resttemplate it always returns me 400 bad request.

```
resttemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, null, String.class)
```

I know that the endpoint returns me json.

When resttemplate finally does execute, it has the correct url and has content-length set to size=1. Not sure if this is the issue.

Comment: post your endpoint too. how you receive requestbody.